# Prediction with randomForest (R) when some inputs have missing values (NA)

Tags: r, predictive-models, random-forest, missing-data

I have a fine `randomForest` classification model which I would like to use in an application that predicts the class of a new case. The new case has inevitably missing values. Predict won't work as such for NAs. How should I do this then?

```
data(iris)
# create first the new case with missing values
na.row<-45
na.col<-c(3,5)
case.na<-iris[na.row,]
case.na[,na.col]<-NA

iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris[-na.row,])
# print(iris.rf)

myrf.pred <- predict(iris.rf, case.na[-5], type="response")
myrf.pred
[1] <NA>
```

I tried `missForest`. I combined the original data and the new case, shaked it with `missForest`, and got imputed values for NAs in my new case. Too heavy computing though.

```
data.imp <- missForest(data.with.na)
```

But there must be a way to use rf-model to predict a new case with missing values, right?

EDIT: in my application the prediction is done on one new case. Simple imputation with mean|median values from the training set is a straightforward solution, but imposes bias on the new case prediction.

Comment: There are many ways missing values can be handled in decision trees, but the `randomForest` package in R only has the imputation method you described.  If you want to stay in a similar environment, `gbm` has a somewhat smoother method of handling missing values in new data (it's not perfect, but it is useful).

Comment: I think that *party* package deals better with missing values

Comment: Dear @Simone, how does `party` package work with NAs in the test set? I couldn't find a trace of imputing in `party` manuals or examples.

Comment: @hermo try to have a look at party's paper http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.92.9930 it seems the algorithm works like CART - it looks for surrogate splits.

Comment: Try using "na.action = na.roughfix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no choice but to impute the values or to change models. A good choice could be aregImpute in the Hmisc package. I think its less heavy than rfimpute which is what is detaining you, first package example (there are others):

```
# Check that aregImpute can almost exactly estimate missing values when
# there is a perfect nonlinear relationship between two variables
# Fit restricted cubic splines with 4 knots for x1 and x2, linear for x3
set.seed(3)
x1 <- rnorm(200)
x2 <- x1^2
x3 <- runif(200)
m <- 30
x2[1:m] <- NA
a <- aregImpute(~x1+x2+I(x3), n.impute=5, nk=4, match='closest')
a
matplot(x1[1:m]^2, a$imputed$x2)
abline(a=0, b=1, lty=2)

x1[1:m]^2
a$imputed$x2

# Multiple imputation and estimation of variances and covariances of
# regression coefficient estimates accounting for imputation
# Example 1: large sample size, much missing data, no overlap in
# NAs across variables
x1 <- factor(sample(c('a','b','c'),1000,TRUE))
x2 <- (x1=='b') + 3*(x1=='c') + rnorm(1000,0,2)
x3 <- rnorm(1000)
y  <- x2 + 1*(x1=='c') + .2*x3 + rnorm(1000,0,2)
orig.x1 <- x1[1:250]
orig.x2 <- x2[251:350]
x1[1:250] <- NA
x2[251:350] <- NA
d <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,y)
# Find value of nk that yields best validating imputation models
# tlinear=FALSE means to not force the target variable to be linear
f <- aregImpute(~y + x1 + x2 + x3, nk=c(0,3:5), tlinear=FALSE,
                data=d, B=10) # normally B=75
f
# Try forcing target variable (x1, then x2) to be linear while allowing
# predictors to be nonlinear (could also say tlinear=TRUE)
f <- aregImpute(~y + x1 + x2 + x3, nk=c(0,3:5), data=d, B=10)
f

# Use 100 imputations to better check against individual true values
f <- aregImpute(~y + x1 + x2 + x3, n.impute=100, data=d)
f
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(f)
modecat <- function(u) {
 tab <- table(u)
 as.numeric(names(tab)[tab==max(tab)][1])
}
table(orig.x1,apply(f$imputed$x1, 1, modecat))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(orig.x2, apply(f$imputed$x2, 1, mean))
fmi <- fit.mult.impute(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, lm, f, 
                       data=d)
sqrt(diag(vcov(fmi)))
fcc <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
summary(fcc)   # SEs are larger than from mult. imputation
```

You mention that you have many new observations that have missing values on the independant variables. Even though you have many cases like this, if for each new observation there is only missings in one or two of its variables and your amount of variables is not tiny maybe just filling the holes up with a median or average (are they continuous?) could work.

Another thing that could be interesting is to do a minor variable importance analysis. The random forest R implementation calculates two importance measures and respective plots:

```
varImpPlot(yourRandomForestModel) # yourRandomForestModel must have the argument importance=TRUE
```

And you can play around with just including "important" variables in the model training, till the prediction accuracy isn't all that affected in comparison to the "full model". Maybe you keep variables with a low number of missings. It could help you reduce the size of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `na.roughfix` when you are predicting more than 1 sample (i.e. predicting for >1 row of data).

For example:

```
data(iris)

# Make some of the data missing
na.row<-c(146,150)
na.col<-c(3,5)
iris[na.row,na.col]<-NA

# Look at NAs
tail(iris)
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5 virginica
# 146          6.7         3.0           NA         2.3      <NA>
# 147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
# 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
# 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
# 150          5.9         3.0           NA         1.8      <NA>

# Run Random Forest on a subset of iris
set.seed(100)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris[1:120,]) #use argument na.action="na.roughfix" if there's NAs in your training set
iris.rf
# Call:
# randomForest(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris[1:120, ]) 
# Type of random forest: classification
# Number of trees: 500
# No. of variables tried at each split: 2
# 
# OOB estimate of  error rate: 4.17%
# Confusion matrix:
#            setosa versicolor virginica class.error
# setosa         50          0         0        0.00
# versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
# virginica       0          2        18        0.10

# Run prediction on test set, using na.roughfix()
myrf.pred <- predict(iris.rf, na.roughfix(iris[121:150,]), type="response")
myrf.pred
#       121        122        123        124        125        126        127        128        129        130        131        132        133        134        135        136 
# virginica versicolor  virginica versicolor  virginica  virginica versicolor versicolor  virginica versicolor  virginica  virginica  virginica versicolor versicolor  virginica 
#       137        138        139        140        141        142        143        144        145        146        147        148        149        150 
# virginica  virginica versicolor  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
# Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

You can see it dealt fine with the NAs.

Comment: This is indeed a good in-built imputation solution for applications where imputation can be run on larger prediction set (>> 1 sample). From the randomForest documentation of na.roughfix: "A completed data matrix or data frame. For numeric variables, NAs are replaced with column medians. For factor variables, NAs are replaced with the most frequent levels (breaking ties at random). If object contains no NAs, it is returned unaltered."